# What Key is System.Windows.Input.Key.Clear

Tags: .net, windows, keyboard

I just realized there is a clear key defined in System.Windows.Input.Key. But the online help just states that it is the ”clear key“. No further information is given.

Can anyone tell me, what this key is and what it does?

Comment: Is this Visual Basic?

Comment: The Apple Keyboard has a Clear Key, maybe thats the key, which you are looking for

Comment: This goes all the way back to Windows version 1.0.  Which defined the virtual key codes that are still used today, like VK_CLEAR in the WinUser.h SDK header file.  Back then terminals were still common, they had a Clear key to erase the line or the screen.  You won't find it back on yours.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its <kbd>5</kbd> on a numpad when <kbd>NumLock</kbd> is off, so at the center of the alternate arrows.